# typescript Symbol.iterator

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, iterator, iterable

I'm trying to create a custom iterable.

here is a simplified example of my code:

```
class SortedArray {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield 1;
        yield 2;
        yield 3;
        return 4;
    }
}
const testingIterables = new SortedArray();
for(let item of testingIterables as any) { // i have to cast it as any or it won't compile
    console.log(item);
}
```

This code will run correctly on ES6 but with TypeScript it will compile and not print the iterable values.

Is this a bug in TypeScript or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Besides Madara's answer, there is also an option to use the [--downlevelIteration flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It isn't a bug. It depends on your target.

TypeScript made a (terrible, in my opinion) design decision that if you transpile TS `for..of` to ES5 or ES3, it emits a normal `for (var i; i < testingIterables.length; i++)` loop.

For that reason, for targets ES5 and ES3, only arrays and strings are allowed in `for..of` loops.

There are several options to remedy this:

- If your TypeScript is over 2.3, you can set the `downlevelIteration` flag to true, this will cause TypeScript to compile iterator correctly, **but it means you must have a Symbol.iterator polyfill in runtime for non-supporting browsers**, else you risk runtime errors in unexpected places for those browsers.
- Select a higher target, ES2015 or higher would work. You can then transpile further down with the use of Babel (you'll also need a runtime polyfill to make Symbols work)
- Unwrap the iterator yourself with the use of `while` and calls to `testingIterables.next()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
seems like you are correct and now everything works. 
Still in my opinion I would consider this as a bug. 
We have to compile our code to ES5 and for a language that claims to be a superset of JavaScript if it forces us to take a code that works fine on ES6 and use babel or unwrap it ourselves then it's just not the behaviour  programmers expect. 
Wouldn't u agree?

Comment: Seems like TypeScript has a compiler flag: `downlevelIteration` since TS2.3, when set to `true` it will assume that you have a polyfill for `Symbol.iterator` and work as expected. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this made it very clear why changing the target was suddenly causing `TS2489: An iterator must have a 'next()' method` errors to appear relating to a class that implemented the iterator interface correctly.