# Building An Iterator With TypeScript And Rollup

Tags: typescript, iterator, rollupjs

I'm writing an application in TypeScript and I'm using Rollup to bundle the files together and Buble / Babel to convert the compiled Javascript into something the browser can use. However, when I run `rollup -c`, I get an error:

```
semantic error TS2495 Type 'Radius' is not an array type or a string type.
```

Not sure what to do about this, as there doesn't seem to be much information about iterators in TypeScript that I can find by the normal search-engine route. Here are my files:

**rollup.config.ts**

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';
import buble from 'rollup-plugin-buble';

export default {
    input: "./chess-player.ts",
    output: {
        file: "./chess-player.min.js",
        format: "iife"
    },
    watch: {
        include: [
            "./chess-player.ts",
            "./src/*/*.ts",
            "./src/*.ts"
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        typescript(),
        buble(),
        uglify()
    ]
};
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "ES2015",
    "strict": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

**radius.ts:**

```
export class Radius implements IterableIterator<number> {
    counter: number;
    max?: number;

    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<number> {
        return this;
    }

    next(): IteratorResult<number> {
        if (!this.max || this.counter < this.max) {
            this.counter++;
            return {
                value: this.counter,
                done: false
            };
        } else {
            this.counter = 0;
            return {
                value: undefined,
                done: true
            };
        }
    }

    constructor(max?: number) {
        this.counter = 0;
        this.max = max;
    }
}
```

An instance of a `Radius` is implemented as a property on the `Piece` class. Here's the method that tries to use it:

```
checkAttackRadius(boardElement: HTMLElement, pieceSquare: Square): void {
    const piece = pieceSquare.piece;
    let vectors = piece.attacks();
    for (let radius of piece.radius) {
        const remaining = this.remaining(vectors);
        if (radius > 14 || remaining === 0) {
            break;
        }
        for (let j = 0; j < vectors.length; j++) {
            this.checkAttackVector(boardElement, pieceSquare, vectors[j], radius);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your compiler settings ? I believe they are not correct because a) `strict` causes an error when you `return {
                value: undefined,
                done: true
            };` b) the error you have is typical for a es5 compilation target

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir No, I'm not sure about my compiler settings! I'm pretty clueless about what to set and just used the defaults, with the exception of setting the `target` and `module` to `ES2015` so that I can use iterators and so that the output is compatible with Rollup. However, I just tried removing `"strict": true,` and ran `rollup -c` again, but got the same result.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590262/typescript-symbol-iterator

Comment: @Tao Correct me if I'm wrong. a) I am compiling to ES2015, so I don't need to use the `downlevelIteration` flag. b) I am compiling to ES2015, then using Babel, so it looks like I need to use a polyfill. Okay, done that, but getting the same result. c) Seems pointless manually calling next() as that the defeats the point of the iterator.

Comment: @Aaron, sorry I guess I should have phrased that 'Maybe this helps' instead of 'See this question'. I remembered seeing a similar question not too long ago and thought it might help you. I suspect rollup to be the culprit. With just ts I only get the error Titian mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've haven't got time to waste on this, besides all the other questions I've found related to this on SO are unanswered, which leads me to think that there is no satisfactory solution.

I ended up deleting the `Radius` class and adding this to the `Piece` class:

```
radius(): { value: number, done: boolean } {
    while(!this.max || this.counter < this.max) {
        this.counter++;
        return {
            value: this.counter,
            done: false
        };
    }
    this.counter = 0;
    return {
        value: undefined,
        done: true
    };
}
```

It's basically a generator without using any ES2015-specific interfaces. Then I just changed the usage of it to a while loop like so:

```
checkAttackRadius(boardElement: HTMLElement, pieceSquare: Square): void {
    const piece = pieceSquare.piece;
    let vectors = piece.attacks();
    let radius = piece.radius();
    while (!radius.done && radius.value <= 14 && this.remaining(vectors) > 0) {
        radius = piece.radius();
        for (let j = 0; j < vectors.length; j++) {
            this.checkAttackVector(boardElement, pieceSquare, vectors[j], radius.value);
        }
    }
}
```